# pandas: merge two data frames in a special order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have checked all the other answers, I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I have a data frame df1:

```
0 A B
1 a good
2 b bad
3 c fair
```

and data frame df2:

```
0 C D
1 a a
2 a b
3 b c
4 a d
```

I want the result to be:

```
0 C B1   D B2
1 a good a good
2 a good b bad
3 b bad  c fair
4 a good d ---
```

Say, df1 plays the role of a 'dictionary', I need to extract the corresponding values of B for A elements.
Note that since the element d is not defined in the df1, corresponding value is '---' in df2.

Seems so simple but can't make it work.
Thanks for all the tips.

Comment: Oh, and I am a beginner, I am sorry if my formatting ins't proper.

Comment: @jezrael Good point, i have added example for that too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`s.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
d=dict(zip(df1.A,df1.B))

df2['B1']=df2.C.map(d).fillna('---')
df2['B2']=df2.D.map(d).fillna('---')

df2=df2[['C','B1','D','B2']]

print(df2)


   C    B1  D    B2
0  a  good  a  good
1  a  good  b   bad
2  b   bad  c  fair
3  a  good  d   ---
```

**For creating a dynamic mapping if there are more columns in df2:**

```
my_list=[]
for i in df2.columns:
    my_list.append(df2[i].map(d).fillna('---'))
df_new=df2.join(pd.concat(my_list,axis=1),lsuffix='',rsuffix='_mapped')
print(df_new)

   C  D C_mapped D_mapped
0  a  a     good     good
1  a  b     good      bad
2  b  c      bad     fair
3  a  d     good      ---
```

Comment: Perfection! The first part works great for even ~50000 rows. Thank you.